# Error when trying to select data from dataframe based on two attributes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to extract a value 'output', which is an int, from the dataframe 'merged' and sum it for all rows containing two attributes. I need to select the value for a specific year and a dummy variable that has been assigned to each row of data, and then sum all of the values that have these two characteristics. I tried to do it like this:

```
sumforyr = merged[merged['year'] == 2000 and merged['dummy'] == 1]['output'].sum()
```

However, running this gives me the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
```

Do I need to loop through each row and check these attributes that way? Is the problem that the Series is evaluated all at once instead of by row?

Comment: `sumforyr  = merged.loc[(merged['year'] == 2000) & (merged['dummy'] == 1), 'output'].sum()`

Comment: Also: merged['sumforyr'] = merged['output'][merged['year'] == 2000 & merged['dummy'] == 1].sum()

Comment: @AndrewL that gives me the same ValueError

Comment: @MaxU that also gives me an error. Is there a typo in your response by chance?

Comment: Updated mine.. does it work?

Comment: @mildlyillogical, no, it should work properly - see a demo in my answer

Comment: Yes, they work now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [21]: merged
Out[21]:
   year  dummy  output
0  2000      1       1
1  2000      1      10
2  2000      2       2
3  2001      3       3

In [22]: merged.loc[(merged['year'] == 2000) & (merged['dummy'] == 1), 'output'].sum()
Out[22]: 11
```